# Check if href exists in td tag python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Below is the `td` print in a loop:

```
<td>0</td>
<td>0</td>
<td></td>
<td class="left" nowrap="nowrap">v <a class="data-link" href="/ci/con/t/8.html">Sri Lanka</a> 
</td>
<td class="left"><a class="data-link" href="/ci/content/gd/58.html">Dambulla</a></td>
<td nowrap="nowrap"><b>1 Aug 2009</b></td>
```

I am using this code:

```
print("href", td.a['href'])
```

Error: `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Updated Per `User-Request`:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = ["<td>0</td>", '<td>0</td>',
        '<td></td>', '<td class="left" nowrap="nowrap">v <a class="data-link" href="/ci/con/t/8.html">Sri Lanka</a> </td>', '<td class="left"><a class="data-link" href="/ci/content/gd/58.html">Dambulla</a></td>', '<td nowrap="nowrap"><b>1 Aug 2009</b></td>']

for item in data:
    item = BeautifulSoup(item, 'html.parser')
    for res in item.findAll("a", {'href': True}):
        print(res.get("href"))
```

Output:

```
/ci/con/t/8.html
/ci/content/gd/58.html
```

Original Answer:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = """
<td>0</td>
<td>0</td>
<td></td>
<td class="left" nowrap="nowrap">v <a class="data-link" href="/ci/con/t/8.html">Sri Lanka</a> 
</td>
<td class="left"><a class="data-link" href="/ci/content/gd/58.html">Dambulla</a></td>
<td nowrap="nowrap"><b>1 Aug 2009</b></td>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

for item in soup.findAll("a", {'href': True}):
    print(item.get("href"))
```

Comment: no bro, the html doesn't come from soup, it is a list of td from a outer loop